# simple jQuery toggle to $("html, body").css({"overflow": "hidden"}); when opened and then switch to "scroll" when closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

The toggle works as you would expect -- and is powered by attaching a class to an element set to open. As you could probably tell below:

*The problem is*.. and you can probably tell from my attempts, is I have three elements that open and close the toggle on click `.isilnk` '`.isi__wrapper`' and `.isi__expander` I am simply trying to set it that when and if the element is expanded or toggle open. *eg.*  `if ($(".isi").hasClass("isi--show-isi")) {` simply set `overflow: hidden` to `html, body` and when it is closed or not open or doesn't have class above, then simply set `html, body { overflow: scroll; }`.

**None of my attempts below allowed for this to work with both open and close**, *only one or the other*. So, currently it works when the element is toggled open, but when it's closed, the `html, body` overflow does not go back to scroll and the user cannot navigate the site.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.isilnk').on('click', function(){
        $('.isi').addClass('isi--show-isi');
        $("html, body").css({"overflow": "hidden"});  
    }); 

    if ($(".isi").hasClass("isi--show-isi")) {
      $("isi__wrapper").css("overflow","scroll");
      $("html, body").css({"overflow": "scroll"});  
    }
    else { 
      $("html, body").css({"overflow": "scroll"});  
    }
    $('.isi__expander').click(function() {
       $("html, body").css({"overflow": "hidden"});  
    });

    $('.isi__wrapper').click(function() { 
        $("html, body").css({"overflow": "scroll"});  
    }
});
```

Comment: could you post html as well ?

Comment: Also, a portion of your code isn't inside the click event function.  i.e. `if ($(".isi").hasClass("isi--show-isi"))` will always execute the `else` statement because it runs once: on document ready.

Comment: Changing that doesn't have a different result..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a guess:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('.isilnk').on('click', function(){
        $('.isi').toggleClass('isi--show-isi');
        $("html, body").css({"overflow": "hidden"});  
        setCSS();
    }); 

    $('.isi__expander').click(function() {
      ('.isi').addClass('isi--show-isi');
      setCSS();
    });

    $('.isi__wrapper').click(function() { 
      ('.isi').removeClass('isi--show-isi');
      setCSS();
    }
});

function setCSS() {
    if ($(".isi").hasClass("isi--show-isi")) {
      $("isi__wrapper").css("overflow","scroll");
      $("html, body").css({"overflow": "scroll"});  
    }
    else { 
      $("html, body").css({"overflow": "scroll"});  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you this does not run for me at all for some reason.

Comment: Can you add your html to the question?